# Get return value of func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPackingWithMediaInfo: [String : AnyObject])

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to access NSURL return value of imagePickerController, but I have no idea as what to enter for the parameters. Is it even possible to get the NSURL from this method, if not, how else should I go about obtaining a NSURL from imagePickerControlle?, As I have been searching for days.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) -> NSURL {

    let theURL: NSURL = (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL)

    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    profilePicture.image = selectedImage

    print("searchthis\(theURL)")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    return theURL
}
```

I want to access "theURL" here:

```
@IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let authInfo = AuthInfo()

    authInfo.email = emailField.text!
    authInfo.firstName = firstField.text!
    authInfo.lastName = lastField.text!
    authInfo.username = usernameField.text!
    authInfo.password = passwordField.text!
    authInfo.profilePicture = profilePicture.image

    let url = imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: ).theURL
    let container = CKContainer.default()
    let privateData = container.privateCloudDatabase

    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Authentication")
    record.setValue(authInfo.email, forKey: "email")
    record.setValue(authInfo.username, forKey: "username")
    record.setValue(authInfo.firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    record.setValue(authInfo.lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    record.setValue(authInfo.password, forKey: "password")
    record.setValue(authInfo.profilePicture, forKey: "profilePicture")
    record.setValue(CKAsset(fileURL: ))
    privateData.save(record, completionHandler: { record, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

    })

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the profile image separately and have to save URL and image in global variables. 
Like:

```
//first register your view controller for image picker delegates

@IBAction func profilePickBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let _mediaPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    _mediaPicker.delegate = self
    _mediaPicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image" as String]
    _mediaPicker.allowsEditing = false
    _mediaPicker.sourceType = .Camera
    self.presentViewController(_mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
//BTW, this is delegate method of picker controller
globalURL = (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL)

globalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
profilePicture.image = selectedImage

print("searchthis\(theURL)")

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then use these globally saved values in this function:

```
@IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

let authInfo = AuthInfo()

...
authInfo.profilePicture = globalImage

let url = globalURL
let container = CKContainer.default()
...

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a brilliant answer. I am kinda new to swift and the the thought of using global variables never entered my mind!

Comment: I marked as answer as answered as it answered what I asked, but do you know what this error could be caused by?                                                                      Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Non-file URL'

Comment: You were calling delegate method by yourself by modifying it, didFinishPicking is delegate and must be called by picker controller!